# TensorFlow tracker class crashing when creating second instantiation - Sessions need to be unique?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I have a TensorFlow tracker which I'm building to conform to the standard OpenCV Tracker format.  These trackers can be used like so (I replaced the calculations and things that don't use tensorflow with `~<this>~`):

```
tracker = cv2.Tracker_create("type")
status_init = tracker.init( initial_frame, bbox)
while True:
    status, frame = camera.read()
    bbox = tracker.update(frame)
    ~<draw bbox onto frame>~
    cv2.imshow("Tracking", frame)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
```

And so this is how I would like to structure the use of my TensorFlow tracker class.

HOWEVER!  Currently my Class code looks like so:

```
class MyTracker(object):
    'My Tracking class code'

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        print "Session Created!"

        def __init__(self, params):
            ~<non-tensorflow object variables being set>~
            self.sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

        def __del__(self):
            print "Session Closed?"

        def init(self, initial_image, initial_bbox)
            try:
                ~<non-tensorflow calculations and things>~
                self.templates = self.sess.run(self.templates_,
                                               feed_dict={
                                                            ~<vars into tf>~
                                                         })
                return True
            except:
                return False

        def update(self, image):
            try:
                ~<non-tensorflow calculations and things>~
                scores_ = self.sess.run(self.scores,
                                        feed_dict={
                                                    ~<vars into tf>~
                                                  })
                ~<more non-tensorflow stuff>~
                bbox = ~<non-tensorflow things>~
                if ~<stuff>~:
                    new_templates = self.sess.run(self.templates_,
                                                  feed_dict={
                                                             ~vars into tf>~
                                                            })
                ~<yet more non-tensorflow calculations>~
                return True, bbox
            except:
                return False, (0, 0, 0, 0)
```

The problem I am experiencing is that I need to be able to create multiple trackers in my code at once, however they attempt to share the same Session and this causes a problem (actually I'm replacing the old one, hoping it will be garbage collected, but I should be able to have two tracker objects if need be):

```
ValueError: Variable conv1/W already exists, disallowed.  Did you mean to set reuse=True in VarScope?
```

I would like any instantiation of this class to create its own Session.  However, instead of using the "with tf.Session() as sess:" wrapper around all of my class member functions I have tried to just add:

```
self.sess = tf.Session()
```

to the `__init__` function to attempt to give each instantiation its own unique Session but it has the **exact** same problem, and in addition I don't get to use the nice `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods which come with the use of the `with` statement.

Since in my test code I'm currently only using one tracker at a time, I can simply call my 'init' function on my tracker object with a new initial_image and initial_bbox without creating a whole new object.

HOWEVER, I need to be able to!

Any help with this annoying problem would be most appreciated!

Comment: This is certainly doable (it sounds like you may want a new tf.Graph associated with each object as well as a session to avoid the variable reuse issues, and may just want to call \_\_enter\_\_/__exit__ manually). However, I would suggest exporting in savedmodel format and using [TensorFlow serving](https://tensorflow.github.io/serving/) instead, if serving is what you're trying to do here.

Comment: I tried calling __enter__/__exit__ manually, but it doesn't seem like the garbage collector does its business fast enough.

Comment: Well, if TF serving isn't an option, I'd suggest turning your class into a context manager as well (so its \_\_exit__ gets called when the user's done with it and you can call \_\_exit__ for the session).